# Compiler optimizations and temporary assignments in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, concurrency, embedded

Please see the following code valid in C and C++:

```
extern int output;
extern int input;
extern int error_flag;

void func(void)
{
  if (0 != error_flag)
  {
    output = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    output = input;
  }
}
```

1. Is the compiler allowed to compile the above code in the same way as if it looked like below?

   ```
   extern int output;
   extern int input;
   extern int error_flag;

   void func(void)
   {
     output = -1;
     if (0 == error_flag)
     {
       output = input;
     }
   }
   ```

   In other words, is the compiler allowed to generate (from the first snippet) code that always makes a temporary assignment of -1 to `output` and then assign `input` value to `output` depending on `error_flag` status?
2. Would the compiler be allowed to do it if `output` would be declared as volatile?
3. Would the compiler be allowed to do it if `output` would be declared as `atomic_int` (stdatomic.h)?

Update after David Schwartz's comment:

If the compiler is free to add additional writes to a variable, it seems it is not possible to tell from the C code whether a data race exists or not. How to determine this?

Comment: You should not care about individual machine instructions (if you do, add `-S -fverbose-asm`  to your optimizations flags for `gcc`). You just need to enable optimizations (`gcc -Wall -mcpu=native -O3`) and **benchmark**

Comment: In theory, if the compiler determines that `error_flag` never changes from its initial value, and its initial value is known, it can compile the function down to a single assignment. The storage class of `output` doesn't matter, it is `error_flag` that determines what happens.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are orthogonal for optimization here, since `output` is meant as _output_, isn't it?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, my concern isn't how to force the compiler to make such optimization, but if such an optimization is allowed. If *output* is read by other threads, is it possible they will read -1 even if *error_flag* is never set?

Comment: @jxh, the compiler cannot determine that, because all the variables are extern. Imagine that `func` is called cyclic in a real time environment and `input` and  `output` are buffers used by different threads.

Comment: My bet is, in this case a good compiler will only make at maximum _one_ read and _one_ assignment to the memory per variable and does the work in registers. This changes when "volatile" is used, then each assignment is made in the order specified, i.e. it will not be reordered.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  What do you mean they are orthogonal? I've corrected the usage of *italic* and `code`.

Comment: For example, if the compiler generates code equivalent to `output = input - (input + 1) * !!error_flag;` would that be a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: @jxh Bad. Is that a trick question?

Comment: I don't think the standard puts any limitations on when optimizations can occur, so data flow analysis at executable link time can determine a more optimal code path.

Comment: and you understand that the implementation of is something equal then is often implemented as if something is not equal branch over the then stuff.  the compiler is free to implement it however they want so long as per the rules of the language it is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, the speculative assignment is possible. Modification of a non-volatile variable is not part of the observable behaviour of the program and thus a spurious write is allowed. (See below for the definition of "observable behaviour", which does not actually include all behaviour which you might observe.)
2. No. If `output` is `volatile`, speculative or spurious mutations are not permitted because the mutation *is* part of observable behaviour. (Writing to -- or reading from -- a hardware register may have consequences other than just storing a value. This is one of the primary use cases of `volatile`.)
3. (**Edited**) No, the speculative assignment is not possible with `atomic` `output`. Loads and stores of `atomic` variables are synchronized operations, so it should not be possible to load a value of such a variable which was not explicitly stored into the variable.

#### Observable behaviour

Although a program can do lots of obviously observable things (for example, abruptly terminating because of a segfault), the C and C++ standards only guarantee a limited set of results. *Observable behaviour* is defined in the C11 draft at §5.1.2.3p6 and in the current C++14 draft at §1.9p8 [intro.execution] with very similar wording:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.
>
> These collectively are referred to as the *observable behavior* of the program.

The above is taken from the C++ standard; the C standard differs in that in the second point it does not allow multiple possible results, and in the third point it explicitly references a relevant section of the standard library requirements. But details aside, the definitions are co-ordinated; for the purpose of this question, the relevant point is that only access to *volatile* variables is observable (up to the point that the value of a non-volatile variable is sent to an output device or file).

#### Data Races

This paragraph needs also to be read in the overall context of the C and C++ standards, which free the implementation from all requirements if the program engenders undefined behaviour. That's why the segfault is not considered in the definition of *observable behaviour* above: the segfault is a possible undefined behaviour but not a possible behaviour in a conformant program. So in the universe of only conformant programs and conformant implementations, there are no segfaults.

That's important because a program with a data race is *not* conformant. A data race has undefined behaviour, even if it seems innocuous. And since it is the responsibility of the programmer to avoid undefined behaviour, the implementation may optimize without regard to data races.

The exposition of the memory model in the C and C++ standards is dense and technical, and probably not suitable as an introduction to the concepts. (Browsing around the material on [Hans Boehm's site](http://www.hboehm.info/) will probably prove less difficult.) Extracting quotes from the standard is risky, because the details are important. But here is a small leap into the morass, from the current C++14 standard, §1.10 [intro.multithread]:

> 6. Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.
>
> …
>
> 23. Two actions are potentially concurrent if
>
>     — they are performed by different threads, or
>
>     — they are unsequenced, and at least one is performed by a signal handler.
>
>     The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

The take-away here is that a read and a write of the same variable need to be synchronized; otherwise it is a data race and the result is undefined behaviour. Some programmers might object to the strictness of this prohibition, arguing that some data races are "benign". This is the topic of [Hans Boehm's 2011 HotPar paper "How to miscompile programs with "benign" data races" (pdf)](http://www.usenix.org/events/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf) (author's summary: "There are no benign data races"), and he explains it all much better than I could.

Synchronization here includes the use of `atomic` types, so it is not a data race to concurrently read and modify an `atomic` variable. (The result of the read is unpredictable, but it must be either the value before the modification or the value afterwards.) This prevents the compiler from performing "piecemeal" modification of an atomic variable without some explicit synchronization.

After some thought and more research, my conclusion is that the compiler cannot perform speculative writes to atomic variables either. Consequently, I modified the answer to question 3, which I had originally answered "no".

Other useful references:

- Bartosz Milewski: [Dealing with Benign Data Races the C++ Way](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/25/dealing-with-benign-data-races-the-c-way/)

  Milewski deals with the precise issue of speculative writes to atomic variables, and concludes:

  > Can’t the compiler still do the same dirty trick, and momentarily store 42 in the `owner` variable? No, it can’t! Since the variable is declared `atomic` the compiler can no longer assume that the write can’t be observed by other threads.
- Herb Sutter on [Thread Safety and Synchronization](http://herbsutter.com/2014/01/13/gotw-95-solution-thread-safety-and-synchronization/)

  As usual, an accessible and well-written explanation.

Comment: 3. Isn't a non-explicit atomic_store defined as atomic_store_explicit with memory_order_seq_cst semantics (the strictest version)? So atomic_store would do the same?

Comment: @2501: Right, I'll change that. Although I think it was implicit.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `atomic_store(&x, v)` on an `atomic` variable `x` is the same as `x.store(u)` which is the same as `x = u`.

Comment: @Florian Yes that was my second though. It is written somewhere in C11 Standard that an assignment of atomic vars is the same as atomic_store. If someone could point out the chapter?

Comment: @rici Can the rule you put in point 1. be found somewhere in the standard (C++ or preferably C)? Is observable behavior a well-defined term?

Comment: @Florian: Yes, indeed, in C++ `x = u` is precisely `atomic_store(&x, u)`, in which the ordering semantics are `memory_order_seq_cst`. C doesn't have the luxury of defining `operator=` and the semantics of the assignment operator are not quite crystal clear, but I think they would be the same. So I went back to my original wording, more or less. Thanks.

Comment: @mrn: edited. My point 1 is essentially an application of the famous "as-if" rule which is based on observable behaviour; I hope the edit meets your needs.

Comment: @rici Thanks for your answer. I still have one doubt. As David Schwartz commented on the second answer, my question is how to determine whether a data race exists at all. Looking at the code, it seems there is no data race, but there is one due to optimizations. I have updated the question.

Comment: David Schwartz's example is interesting (and probably the transformation in that case is invalid), because the variable `i` is not referenced at all when the `if` condition is false. (The fact that it is a constant `false` is not relevant.) But your question is different: `output` is always modified, and consequently any non-synchronized read of `output` is already a data race. (Many programmers would call this a "benign" data race, but they would be wrong.) So the speculative write cannot create a data race which doesn't already exist. I'll update the answer with a definition of "data race".

Comment: @mrn: Also, I changed my mind about speculative writes to atomic variables. So the newly-edited answer says "Yes, No, No." Mea culpa.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler is allowed to do that kind of optimization. In general, you can assume that the compiler (and the CPU too) can reorder your code assuming it is running in a single thread. If you have more than one thread, you need to synchronize. If you don't synchronize and your code writes to a memory location that is written to or read by another thread, your code contains a data race, in C++ this is undefined behavior.

`volatile` doesn't change the data race problem. However IIRC, the compiler is not allowed to reorder reads and writes to a `volatile` variable.

When using `atomic_int`, the compiler can still perform certain optimizations. I don't think that the compiler can invent writes though (that could break a multithreaded program). However, it can still reorder operations, so be careful.

Comment: "*If you don't synchronize and your code writes to a memory location that is written to or read by another thread, your code contains a data race, in C++ this is undefined behavior.*" I think you miss the point of his question. His question is whether the compiler can "optimize" his code in a way that adds a write, such that his code contains a data race only when optimized. If the compiler is free to optimize code such that it contains additional writes, how can you ever know whether or not your code writes to memory that is read by another thread?

Comment: For example, consider `if (false) i++;`. This code clearly has no data race. But if the compiler is free to optimize it to `i++; if (true) i--;` then maybe it does. His question is about how to tell whether your code has a data race (and thus requires synchronization) or not if the compiler is free to optimize it in a way that adds writes.

Comment: @David Schwartz This is exactly my question, I will add this point explicitly to the question.

Comment: @mrn The short answer to your question is this: Either your compiler provides guarantees that allow you to write sane multi-threaded code or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then don't use it to compile multi-threaded code. Use a compiler that does.